# Drawbacks of logging method names with Log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Adding the source method of run-time errors in logs can greatly increase the efficiency of solving issues and is a valuable tool in debugging large-scale projects. For example, Log4j can add this information to its logs if some flags (ex. `%M`) are set in the `PatternLayout` of the log appender.

However, the [Apache documentation of PatternLayout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html) issues the following warning concerning logs that contain source method names:

> **WARNING** Generating caller location information is extremely slow and should be avoided unless execution speed is not an issue.

Does anyone have (authoritative) experience on how much this is true in real-world situations? Should such logging really be "avoided" or is it acceptable given its considerable debugging benefits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely wouldn't want it in hot code. It's probably going to be using an Exception's stack trace to do it, which really is quite slow.

Log4j has configurable logging levels. I suggest you only enable this feature in debug-level logging. You should avoid this during normal operation.

Comment: Tie the logger instance to the class name.  Then assuming the message is reasonably distinctive, you should be able to easily determine the method/problem when reviewing the logs.

Comment: That's a point: when you want to know where a log message comes from, surely you can just search your code for a substring of the message and find it?

... So why would you want this feature in the first place?